# Javascript: using xml id attributes to getElementById

Tags: javascript, xml, dtd

I'm trying to get getElementById to work with an XML structure. In this case, I am creating web pages based on two xml files: positions and personnel. I create a logical link between them by using a modified "person's name" (with blanks replaced by underscores and apostrophes & periods removed) as the incumbent in the position file. The same thing is set as an id attribute in the personnel file.

The dtd for the personnel file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE people [
   <!ELEMENT person (name, email?, bio?, telephone*)>
        <!ATTLIST person id ID #REQUIRED > 
        <!ELEMENT name              (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT email (email-name, email-domain)>
            <!ELEMENT email-name    (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT email-domain  (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT bio (photo?, p*, li*)>
            <!ELEMENT photo         (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT p             (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT li            (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT telephone (tel-type?, tel-area, tel-num, tel-ext?)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-type      (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-area      (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-num       (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-ext       (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
```

The data gets loaded into peopleList but

```
var incumbentDetails = peopleList.getElementById(curIncumbent);
```

fails. I've verified that curIncumbent contains the correct (and valid) information and checked for duplicate ids (there aren't any). I've verified that I've loaded the correct number of "person" elements.

A person element would look like this:

```
    <person id="John_Doe">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <email>
            <email-name>jd123456</email-name>
            <email-domain>mymail.com</email-domain>
        </email>
        <bio>
            <photo>images/people/JohnDoe.jpg</photo>
            <p>John Doe is a fictitious employee.</p>
            <li>Accomplishment Item 1</li>
            <li>Accomplishment Item 2</li>
        </bio>
        <telephone>
            <tel-area>123</tel-area>
            <tel-num>456-7890</tel-num>
        </telephone>
    </person>
```

To make matters even stranger, when I replace the getElementById with a loop that goes through the list until it finds the correct attribute, it works.

```
    for (var k=0; k<peopleList.length; k++) {
        var thisIncumbent = peopleList[k].getAttribute("id");
alert('found ' + thisIncumbent);
        if (thisIncumbent == curIncumbent) { break; }
    }
```

exits after displaying the correct id. Obviously this is a lot slower than using getElementById so it's not a good solution. Nor does sorting the list and doing a binary search seem like a reasonable alternative (still slower and too easy to get an id in the wrong order).

The code that loads the files is:

```
var fileLoader;

function loadListener() {
    var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
    fileLoader(xmlDoc);
}

function errorListener(e) {
    alert('error loading file: ' + e.statusText);
}

function importXML(fileName, loadFunction) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (loadFunction) {
        fileLoader = loadFunction;
    } else {
        fileLoader = loadTable;
    }
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", loadListener);
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("error", errorListener);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", fileName);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

While this is similar to another question, a close look at the other question shows that it was essentially unresolved, although there were many irrelevant issues raised and rebutted in it. For example, the assertion that getElementById can't be used against XML objects is rejected by https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/re420.html as well as by the second answer below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `peopleList` exactly? I first assumed it was an element but now I realize it might rather be a NodeList or alike? Anyway, it's certainly not a Document if your loop did work.

Comment: It's the XML file thats been loaded that uses the DTD shown. It contains all the people elements. That's why I'm trying to get a person with the correct id from it.

Comment: Show how you get this object. Certainly it's not a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) either. To use the `getElementById` method you need to have access to a `Document` object (or a `DocumentFragment`).

Comment: I get the documents using an xmlhttp GET request to open and load the files. This part is clearly working since both XML structures are clearly in memory. This is verified by the loop kludge that finds the incumbent in the people list. Modern browsers allow getElementById to be used with any XML object that contains ID attributes, as ThW demonstrates below.

Comment: But they are getting a [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object through `DOMParser.parseFromString()` you clearly aren't since otherwise your loop wouldn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/z3vLq1j9/ So once again, what is this mysterious `peopleList` you have that does have a `.length` property? How do you get this object? Show the code.

Comment: Regarding your edits, you are clearly missing the point. `.getElementById()` is  a method of the Document interface. You need an instance of this interface to be able to use it. `peopleList` **is not an instance of `Document`**, because such objects don't have a `.length` property and you can't iterate through them like you do in the code you said works. Nobody ever said that you can't do `getElementById` in an XML Document, what we said is that you need a Document to do so. Please do `console.log(peopleList)` and tell us what this outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the new code, but that's still missing where `peopleList` is being defined. If you were calling `xmlDoc.getElementById()` then that would work, but once again, `peopleList` is not the same object as `xmlDoc`.

Comment: OK. I get it. Thanks. A list of xml elements differs from an xml document with a list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parser is not using the DTD, so the attribute is just an attribute named `id`. You could use query selector or xpath.

The following example shows that `getElementById()` works and demonstrates the
use of query selector (for the child element).

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const people = parser.parseFromString(getXMLString(), 'text/xml');

// fetch by id
const person = people.getElementById('John_Doe');

// use query selector to access child element
console.log(person.querySelector('name')?.textContent);

// use query selector only - fetch by attribute value
console.log(
    people.querySelector('person[id="John_Doe"] > name')?.textContent
);

function getXMLString() {
  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE people [
   <!ELEMENT person (name, email?, bio?, telephone*)>
        <!ATTLIST person id ID #REQUIRED > 
        <!ELEMENT name              (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT email (email-name, email-domain)>
            <!ELEMENT email-name    (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT email-domain  (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT bio (photo?, p*, li*)>
            <!ELEMENT photo         (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT p             (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT li            (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT telephone (tel-type?, tel-area, tel-num, tel-ext?)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-type      (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-area      (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-num       (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT tel-ext       (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
<people>  
    <person id="John_Doe">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <email>
            <email-name>jd123456</email-name>
            <email-domain>mymail.com</email-domain>
        </email>
        <bio>
            <photo>images/people/JohnDoe.jpg</photo>
            <p>John Doe is a fictitious employee.</p>
            <li>Accomplishment Item 1</li>
            <li>Accomplishment Item 2</li>
        </bio>
        <telephone>
            <tel-area>123</tel-area>
            <tel-num>456-7890</tel-num>
        </telephone>
    </person>
</people>
  `
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?

I've tried this with both Firefox ESR and Chromium and it doesn't work with either. However the xml documentation that I've found says both (and all modern major browsers) should support getElementById out of the box.

I've tested my loop kludge and it behaves correctly whether or not it finds the element with the correct id so it doesn't look like a it's an xml error either - both tables load correctly and all the elements seem to be being processed.

While it's nice to know that my code should be working, it still isn't.  :(

Comment: I am clicking `Run Script` of the example and it outputs the expected "John Doe" in the integrated console. In Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for some broader insight into why a toy example with one table works while my actual data, with two tables and more data fails. What would cause getElementById to fail while allowing a linear search to work?

Comment: Can't debug without knowing your source and the error messages. Separate parts like in your question only allow some guesses. That is why I consolidated it into a minimal example. Does the response XML include the DTD (like in my example)?